# Problema testeando una API con Postman

Tags: api, mongodb, postman

Hice una **API CRUD** con `nodejs`, `mongodb`, `mongoose` y la estoy testeando con **Postman**. 
El problema que tengo es que los datos no se ingresan correctamente a la `BDD`. 
Lo que obtengo cuando intento quiero ver los datos es la primera imagen, que es en el cluster de `mongodb` atlas. 
En la segunda imagen esta mi configuracion `config.js`
La tercera imagen es lo que coloco en el post en postman.
Y en la cuarta imagen es lo que coloco en el get en postman.

[image]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y porque piensas que el problema es postman y no tu codigo?

Comment: Puede estar en mi código por eso lo pregunto, nunca dije que fuera problema de las herramientas que uso

Comment: Pero no estas mostrando tu codigo