# Problema con una API en Postman

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

Hice una API CRUD con nodejs, mongodb, mongoose y la estoy testeando con Postman. 
El problema que tengo es que los datos no se ingresan correctamente a la BDD. Lo que obtengo cuando intento quiero ver los datos es el siguiente codigo, que es en el cluster de mongodb atlas:

```
"_id":"5d546be158986416341bf17c"},
"title":"No product title",
"createdAt":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1565813729193"}},
"updatedAt":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1565813729193"}},
"__v":0
```

Esta es mi configuración config.js

```
module.exports = {
    url: 'mongodb+srv://admin2:admin@cluster0-owryq.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
    serverport: 3000 
}
```

Esto es lo que coloco en el post en postman.

```
{"tittle": "MacBook", "description": "13 inch Macbook pro", "price":"1200", "company": "Apple"}
```

Lo que obtengo en el get en postman es básicamente lo mismo que veo en el mongodb atlas, el primer código que mostré.

Este es mi server.js

```
// get dependencies
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

// parse requests
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

//Enable CORS for all HTTP methods
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
  });

// Configuring the database
const config = require('./config.js');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('./product.routes.js')(app);  //Add route file here

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

// Connecting to the database
mongoose.connect(config.url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true
}).then(() => {
    console.log("Successfully connected to the database");    
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('Could not connect to the database. Exiting now...', err);
    process.exit();
});

// default route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({"message": "Welcome to ZeptoBook Product app"});
});

// listen on port 3000
app.listen(config.serverport, () => {
    console.log("Server is listening on port 3000");
});
```

Aqui coloque las imágenes de lo que mostré en los códigos de arriba [Problema testeando una API con Postman](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/286040/problema-testeando-una-api-con-postman) Pregunta que eliminaré después

Comment: Hola, falta que agregues el código en donde recibes la solicitud POST desde el cliente. Saludos

Comment: Lo que obtengo luego del POST es el primer código que inserte

Comment: Entiendo que lo primero que has insertado es la respuesta. Pero se requiere el código que genera dicha respuesta del lado servidor. Por poner, se requiere el código de `app.post(...)`. Saludos

Answer (score -1):

```
_id":"5d546be158986416341bf17c"},
"title":"No product title",
"createdAt":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1565813729193"}},
"updatedAt":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1565813729193"}},
"__v":0
```

Esta es mi configuración config.js

```
module.exports = {
    url: 'mongodb+srv://admin2:admin@cluster0-owryq.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
    serverport: 3000 
}
```

Comment: Las publicaciones que son básicamente código sin ninguna explicación se consideran de baja calidad porque no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios. Por favor, edita la respuesta para añadir una descripción de qué es lo que hace este código, dónde iría, y cómo resuelve el problema. Lee [answer] para más información.